# Sobolev space $W^{k,p}_0$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Given a smooth domain $\Omega$, one can define the sobolev space

$$W_{k,p}^0 = \text{ closure of } C_c^{\infty} \text{ in } W_{k,p}(U)$$

One interpretation of this space is given in the book Partial Differential Equations by Evans as

$W^{k,p}_0$ comprises those functions in $W^{k,p}(U)$ such that

$$
``D^{\alpha}u = 0" \text{ on } \partial \Omega \qquad \forall |\alpha| \leq k-1
$$

Why is the $|\alpha| = k$ not included in this interpretation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; can you add more details? Are you familiar with the proof, at least for the case $k=1$? This would answer "why" in a way. And considering the case $k=0$ yourself can also shed some light on the problem.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Doesn't the $W_{k,p}$ norm include the derivative of up to $k$th order? So intuitively the $k$-th derivative of $u$ in $W_{k,p}$ should have zero boundary. Shouldn't it? What is special about the highest order derivative?

Comment: Well, it depends on your intuition. I really think it would help if you considered the case $k=0$ and also read the proof in Evans' book (and included your thoughts or doubts about it in the question).